# Multiprocessing a loop inside another loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This code processes multiple PDFs one at a time.  Within each PDF, it is looping through each page using opencv to detect if each page is a 4up page vs 1up page, and if it is a 4up page, the loop appends the index of that page to a list named "ind".  Since the order of the pages being processed doesn't matter, I would like to multiprocess the opencv detection.  But I'm a complete newb in Python, so can't seem to get it working using Pool function.
This is the original code (single-threaded)

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import cv2
import numpy as np

pdffiles = 'sample.pdf'
for p in pdffiles: 
    pages=convert_from_path(pdffiles)   
    ind = []
    for i in range(len(pages)):
     page = pages[i]
     gray = np.array(page)
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     (thresh, bw) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
     edges = cv2.Canny(bw,0,255)
     minLineLength=850
     lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=5,theta=np.pi/90, threshold=1000,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=3)
     linessub = lines[((lines[:,0,0]>750) & (lines[:,0,0]<950))|((lines[:,0,1]>1000) & (lines[:,0,1]<1200))]
     if len(linessub) > 1: ind.append(i)
     
print(ind)
```

edit: I've simplified what I posted to just include the section I'm trying to multiprocess.  You should be able to run the code on the sample.pdf that I've uploaded here: on this file, the ind that prints should be `[1,2]`
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2dvpex7njvon6r/sample.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Python is single threaded because of the `Global Interpreter Lock`. Write a script that spawns multiple python interpreters and combine the results.

Comment: @stuck what would you like to multiprocess here exactly? You stated you would like to process the pdf's one at a time, and at the second code (you have tried), there is no loop through the pages, you just pass that to the funtion. Is `pages` a list?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can process things simultaneously.  Multiprocessing and Threading.  You'd have to try which works better for you.

**Threading**

This is a basis example and to help you on the way.

```
import threading

results = []
threads = []


def task(arg):
    results.append(arg)


for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=task)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

print results
```

Below would be an example applied on your code.  I couldn't run your example so this isn't tested.

```
import threading
import timeit

curdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.chdir(curdir)
files = os.listdir(curdir)
if os.environ.get('OS','') == 'Windows_NT':
    dstdir = os.path.join(curdir, '1up\\')
else:
    dstdir = os.path.join(curdir, '1up/')
if not os.path.exists(dstdir):
   os.makedirs(dstdir)
pdffiles = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.pdf')]

ind = []

def 4up_detect(pages):
    gray = np.array(pages)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (thresh, bw) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    edges = cv2.Canny(bw,0,255)
    minLineLength=1100
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=5,theta=np.pi/90, threshold=1000,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=3)
    linessub = lines[((lines[:,0,0]>750) & (lines[:,0,0]<950))|((lines[:,0,1]>1000) & (lines[:,0,1]<1200))]
    if len(linessub) > 1: 
        ind.append(pages)



threads = []

for p in pdffiles: 
    pages=convert_from_path(p)  
    t = threading.Thread(target=4up_detect, args=[pages])
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

startpg = min(ind)
endpg = max(ind)
page = pages[startpg]
image = np.array(page)
height = int(math.floor(image.shape[0])/2)
width = int(math.floor(image.shape[1])/2)
```

**Multiprocessing**

With processing you want to add a shared variable to pass on the results.
A minimal working example can look like this:

```
import multiprocessing

def task(arg, results):
    '''worker function'''
    results.append(arg)


manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
results = manager.list()
procs = []
for i in range(10):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=task, args=(i,results))
    procs.append(p)
    p.start()

for i in procs:
    i.join()

print(results)
```

This is roughly how that could look in your code.  However again, I couldn't run it:

```
import multiprocessing
import timeit


def 4up_detect(pages, results):
    gray = np.array(pages)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    (thresh, bw) = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    edges = cv2.Canny(bw,0,255)
    minLineLength=1100
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=5,theta=np.pi/90, threshold=1000,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=3)
    linessub = lines[((lines[:,0,0]>750) & (lines[:,0,0]<950))|((lines[:,0,1]>1000) & (lines[:,0,1]<1200))]
    if len(linessub) > 1: 
        results.append(pages)


curdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.chdir(curdir)
files = os.listdir(curdir)
if os.environ.get('OS','') == 'Windows_NT':
    dstdir = os.path.join(curdir, '1up\\')
else:
    dstdir = os.path.join(curdir, '1up/')
if not os.path.exists(dstdir):
   os.makedirs(dstdir)
pdffiles = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.pdf')]

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
ind = manager.list()
procs = []

for p in pdffiles: 
    pages=convert_from_path(p)  
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=task, args=(pages, ind))
    procs.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in procs:
    p.join()


startpg = min(ind)
endpg = max(ind)
page = pages[startpg]
image = np.array(page)
height = int(math.floor(image.shape[0])/2)
width = int(math.floor(image.shape[1])/2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I've tried it both ways and the def 4up_detect line seem to have a syntax error: def 4up_detect(pages, results):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

Comment: @SD it turns out the syntax error is due to the name of the function starting with a number (4up).  When I renamed it to (fourup) the error is gone.  However, now when I use the multi-thread method above, it seems the line: gray = np.array(pages) doesn't like that pages is a List.  {TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'PpmImageFile'}

Comment: Since I'm only interested in multiprocess the pages loop inside the pdffiles loop, it seems I have to add this line  { for i in range(len(pages)):  } and put the multiprocessing lines under that.  But then the original function in def fourup doesn't have access to the index number of the page it is processing...

Comment: I would probably just read all the pages inside all of the files and stick them in a list.  Then send them to the threads for processing.  

Try to keep things simple, especially for debugging - multiprocessing is no joke to debug :)